# Boost Context library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-context

In the most recent version of the Boost the new library [Context](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/overview.html) appeared.

After reading the documentation I understood what it does, but can hardly see the use-cases. What are the benefits of using this library? For which tasks you could recommend to use it?

Comment: I think they explain that it is an infrastructure for building cooperative multithreading.

Comment: The phrase to Google is "cooperative multitasking" (not multithreading -- the point is that it is single-threaded). The biggest advantage is super-fast task switching (that doesn't involve the OS). If you've Googled that and still have questions, then ask away :-)

Comment: Please don't redirect me to Google before you read the question. I'm interested to know SO community opinion on Boost.Context library, share experience of using it, pros and cons comparing to analogs, etc

Comment: libcppa (C++ Actors) uses Boost.Context, AFAIK

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a basis for coroutine library, that is under review as of early september 2012, so it should appear in some future release. That will allow easy implementation of things like generators like in [python](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/classes.html#generators) or [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) have them.

The context library itself can be compared to scheme's [`call-with-current-continuation`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_754) and `call-with-dynamic-root` functions. A basis for various kinds of coroutines, generators and cooperative threads.

**Update:** [Coroutine library](http://www.boost.org/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) is included in Boost since version 1.53.

Comment: The review of the Coroutine library has started, the documentation draft can be found [here](http://ok73.ok.funpic.de/boost/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: How long does a Boost review normally take? If no issues are found, when will it be included?